# Testing background save of Core Data entity with Kiwi

Tags: ios, unit-testing, core-data, grand-central-dispatch, kiwi

I'm struggling to figure out the best method to test interacting with Core Data in a background thread. I have the following class method:

```
+ (void)fetchSomeJSON
{
    // Download some json then parse it in the block
    [[AFHTTPClient sharedClient] fetchAllThingsWithCompletion:^(id results, NSError *error) {
        if ([results count] > 0) {

            NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundContext = //... create a new context for background insertion
            dispatch_queue_t background = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);

            dispatch_async(background, ^{ // If I comment this out, my test runs just fine

                //... insert and update some entities
                for (NSString *str in results) {
                    NSManagedObject *object = //...
                }
            });
        }
    }];
}
```

I'm currently testing this method with the following Kiwi code:

```
describe(@"MyAction", ^{

    __block void (^completionBlock)(NSArray *array, NSError *error);

    beforeEach(^{
        // Stub the http client
        id mockClient = [AFHTTPClient mock];
        [WRNAPIClient stub:@selector(sharedClient) andReturn:mockClient];

        // capture the block argument
        KWCaptureSpy *spy = [mockClient captureArgument:@selector(fetchAllThingsWithCompletion:) atIndex:0];
        [MyClass fetchSomeJSON]; // Call the method so we can capture the block
        completionBlock = spy.argument;

        // run the completion block 
        completionBlock(@[@"blah"], nil);
    })

    // If I remove the dispatch_async block, this test passes fine. 
    // If I add it in again the test fails, probably because its not waiting
    it(@"should return the right count", ^{
        // entityCount is a block that performs a fetch request count
        NSInteger count = entityCount(moc, @"Task");
        [[theValue(count) should] equal:theValue(4)];
    })

    // This works fine, but obviously I don't want to wait a second
    it(@"should return the right count after waiting for a second", ^{
        sleep(1);
        NSInteger count = entityCount(moc, @"Task");
        [[theValue(count) should] equal:theValue(4)];
    });

};
```

If I remove the `dispatch_async` line, then I can get my test to run quickly. The only way I can get my test suite to run when using `dispatch_async` is to `sleep(1)` after calling the completion block. Using `sleep()` makes me think that I'm not approaching it in the right way. I have tried using `shouldEventually` but this doesn't seem to re-fetch my `count` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried these asynchronous block macros?

```
#define TestNeedsToWaitForBlock() __block BOOL blockFinished = NO
#define BlockFinished() blockFinished = YES
#define WaitForBlock() while (CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0, true) && !blockFinished)
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, but it looks like a much more succinct way of waiting.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried several approaches to solving this, none feel right.

---

**1) Move the `dispatch_async` to its own class**

```
+ (void)dispatchOnMainQueue:(Block)block
{
    if ([NSThread currentThread] == [NSThread mainThread]) {
        block();
    } else {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block);
    }
}

+ (void)dispatchOnBackgroundQueue:(Block)block
{
    dispatch_queue_t background = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
    dispatch_async(background, block);
}
```

Then during test execution, swizzle the background dispatch to occur on the main queue. This worked, but was unpredictable. It also felt so wrong!

---

**2) Move the setup code to `Kiwi`'s `beforeAll` block, then sleep the main thread.** This works as the `Kiwi` tests are run on the main thread, so we're effectively saying "let the background operations happen before carrying on with the tests". I think this is what I'm going to use. Yes it makes my unit tests run slower, but they pass when they should do, and fail when they should

```
describe(@"MyAction", ^{

    __block void (^completionBlock)(NSArray *array, NSError *error);

    beforeAll(^{
        // Stub the http client
        id mockClient = [AFHTTPClient mock];
        [WRNAPIClient stub:@selector(sharedClient) andReturn:mockClient];

        // capture the block argument
        KWCaptureSpy *spy = [mockClient captureArgument:@selector(fetchAllThingsWithCompletion:) atIndex:0];
        [WRNTaskImporter importAllTasksFromAPI];
        completionBlock = spy.argument;

        // run the completion block 
        completionBlock(@[@"blah"], nil);

        // Wait for background import to complete
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];

    })

    // This works 
    it(@"should return the right count", ^{
        // entityCount is a block that performs a fetch request count
        NSInteger count = entityCount(moc, @"Task");
        [[theValue(count) should] equal:theValue(4)];
    })
};
```

The caveat of this approach is that it only works when you aren't changing any data before a test. Say for example I insert 4 entities, and want to check each entity was inserted as expected. This option would work here. If I needed to re-run the import method and check that the count hadn't increased, I would need to add another `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1]` after calling the insertion code.

---

For normal block based `Kiwi` tests you should probably use either the `expectFutureValue shouldEventually` method, or `KWCaptureSpy` to test your code, but this may not help when calling nested blocks.

If anyone has a more appropriate method for testing cases like these I'm happy to hear it!